# Javascript variable to PHP using Jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following javascript function

```
function success_callback(p)
    {

        lat = p.coords.latitude.toFixed(2);
        lon = p.coords.longitude.toFixed(2);

    }
```

Now I want to transfer both the variable to PHP using Jquery AJAX, I am pretty new to Jquery, I am not able to figure out how to do it. I want to transfer the variables to the same PHP file where this JS code resides. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. You could post the variables using the data string. Have a look at the [Manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: "lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon,
  success: function(){
      //callback code
      alert("Done!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using ajax call, you can send values to another php file, in case of same file needs to use condition needs to be checked.but best is to pass parameters to another file for pressing.
Where you wanted to use/why you wants those on same page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). The syntax is easy

```
function success_callback(p) {

    lat = p.coords.latitude.toFixed(2);
    lon = p.coords.longitude.toFixed(2);
    var coords = {
        lat: lat,
        long: lon
    };
    $.get('mypage.php', coords, function () {
        alert('data sent');
    });

}
```

And in your PHP script, you use the $_GET

```
$lat = isset($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['lat'] : 0;
$long = isset($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['long'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**javascript:**

```
$.get('index.php?lat='+ lat + '&long=' + lon)
```

**php:**

```
$lat = isset($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['lat'] : 0;
$lon = isset($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['long'] : 0;
```

If your current page is named index.php.
Keep in mind the current page is going to process again unless you specifically program your php not to.  You asked to send it to the current page, though, so that is what this does.