# How to pass a variable from Jquery to PHP using Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

How do i pass a variable from Jquery to PHP?

```
var itemId = $(this).attr('name');
$.ajax({
    url: "loaditems.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(result){
    alert(result);
}});
```

I want to add a number in PHP at the end of my SQL request.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM SmiteItems WHERE ID = ";
```

I know there are many questions like this, but other questions are made by people who have more complicated structures which i don't understand.

Comment: Show us how you run the query so I can tell you that it's probably vulnerable

Comment: There must be 1,000 examples on SO alone and 1,000,000 on the internet in tutorials etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript variable to PHP using Jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110140/javascript-variable-to-php-using-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the POST method, then try using PHP PDO for making sql queries 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

```
 var itemId = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        url: "loaditems.php",
        method: "POST", //change
        data: { myVar: itemId }
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

Then in your PHP code

```
 //Get post value from AJAX
    $itemId = $_POST['myVar'];

    \\PDO Example
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM SmiteItems WHERE ID = ?";
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindparam(1, $itemId);
    $result->execute();
```

Comment: Why it must be the POST method?

Comment: Yes it was because of the method. GET is only getting data, but when i want to specify "what data i want" aka "i want only the names column" it must be post.

Answer (score -2):

add `data` in ajax call and use that data in target url:

```
var itemId = $(this).attr('name');
$.ajax({
    url: "loaditems.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {number:itemId},
    success: function(result){
    alert(result);
    }
});
```

and then in loaditems.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM SmiteItems WHERE ID = " . $_GET['number'];
```

As this is not a database and security question, I write no more about **SQL INJECTION**. Please use "post" method and read more about injection.

Comment: Use POST instead ?

Comment: The sql query is prone to sql injection when left like this! You need to escape any user input before passing it to the database! Also, use the '.' concatenation operator instead of numerical '+'.

Comment: I have updated the code from `+` to `.` For difference between get and post security, please check this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33837/get-vs-post-which-is-more-secure
@MehdiBounya

Comment: @AliSheikhpour GET is not secure for sensitive data, but you can still use GET for GETting data, but that depends on the context I guess...

Comment: You are right. Get and Post is not the context of this question. I had no idea why my answer was downvoted so I added a few details about security.